# Unhide a Document Set in XCode

Tags: xcode, macos

I fat-fingered my XCode Doc Set in two ways:

entered the wrong password/name, and it doesn't prompt for a new one (I'll solve this in a little time)

accidentally hit "Hide Doc Set" when I right clicked it, trying to figure out how to reset the name / password to try to subscribe.

where'd it go?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom-left of the listing of doc sets is a button that brings up a menu with the option you're looking for.